# Is this a metric on the shift space?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Consider
$$
\Omega_N:=\left\{\omega=(\ldots,\omega_{-1},\omega_0,\omega_1,\ldots): \omega_i\in\left\{0,1,\ldots,N-1\right\}\text{ for }i\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}
$$
and
$$
\Omega_N^R:=\left\{\omega=(\omega_0,\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots): \omega_i\in\left\{0,1,\ldots,N-1\right\}\text{ for }i\in\mathbb{N}_0\right\}.
$$

> I wonder, if then
>   $$
> d(x,y)=\begin{cases}2^{-(\ell-k)}\text{ if }k,\ell\text{ are maximal such that }x_{[k,\ell]}=y_{[k,\ell]}\\0, x=y\end{cases}
> $$
>   is a metric on both $\Omega_N$ and $\Omega_N^R$.

I think yes! However, I would like to hear your YES or NO, because I am not totally sure.

Comment: Did you check the axioms of a metric space, or what makes you "think" yes? Is there some particular part that puzzles you?

Comment: Yes, I did check. To my opinion, only $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(y,z)$ may be wrong, the other two seem clear to me.

Comment: Maybe in case $x\neq y$, I should have written $2^{-n},$ if $n:=\ell-k$ is maximal such that $x_{[k,\ell]}=y_{[k,\ell]}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\zeta\in\Omega_N^R$ be the constant $0$ sequence, and define $\omega=\langle\omega_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle\in\Omega_N^R$ as follows:

$$\omega_k=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }k=2^n\text{ for some }n\in\Bbb N\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Then $\omega$ agrees with $\zeta$ on arbitrarily long segments, but $\omega\ne\zeta$, so $d(\omega,\zeta)$ is undefined. For that matter, if we set $\omega_0=1$ and $\omega_k=0$ for $k>0$, then $\omega$ agrees with $\zeta$ on an infinite segment. The situation with $\Omega_N$ is just as bad.

For $\Omega_N^R$ you can fix matters by defining

$$\delta(x,y)=\min\{k\in\Bbb N:x_k\ne y_k\}$$

for $x\ne y$ and then setting $d(x,y)=2^{-\delta(x,y)}$.

For $\Omega_N$ you can do something similar: if $x\ne y$ let

$$\delta(x,y)=\min\{k\in\Bbb N:x_k\ne y_k\text{ or }x_{-k}\ne y_{-k}\}\;,$$

and then set $d(x,y)=2^{-\delta(x,y)}$.

In both cases you get a metric, and the space itself is of course a Cantor set.

Comment: I can use that f.e. to show that the periodic points (under the left-shift) in $\Omega_N^R$ are dense, right? Let $x\in\Omega_N^R$. Then $x\in C_{\alpha}^{m}:=\left\{\omega\in\Omega_N^R | \omega_i=\alpha_i\text{ for } i=0,...,m\right\}$. The point $z=(z_0,z_1,\ldots)$ with $z_n=\alpha_{k}$ for $k\leq m, k=n (\text{mod} m+1)$ is a periodic point with period $m+1$ and $d(x,z)=2^{-(m+1)}$. Choosing $m$ big enough, then $d(x,z)<\varepsilon$ for any given $\varepsilon >0$. Is that okay?

Comment: @Salamo: Yes. The sets $C_\alpha^m$ are a base for the topology, and each contains (infinitely many) periodic points.

Comment: That is. The cylinder sets $C_{\alpha}^m$ generate the topology on $X=\left\{0,1,...,N-1\right\}^{\mathbb{N}_0}$ and therefore one can write $X$ as an union of cylinder sets $C_{\alpha}^m$?

Comment: @Salamo: The open sets in $X$ are precisely the unions of cylinder sets.

Comment: I see that each cylinder set contains periodic points (by the construction I gave). But if now for example $x\in\left\{w\in\Omega_N^R: x_2=\alpha_2,x_3=\alpha_3,x_4=\alpha_4\right\}$ how can I approximate x by such a periodic point? Because $x$ I can put x also in a "bigger" cylinder set - as long as the postions 2 to 4 remain the same? For example x is in $\left\{\omega: x_0=\beta_0,x_1=\beta_1,x_2=\alpha_2,x_3=\alpha_3,x_4=\alpha_4,x_5=\beta_5,\ldots ,x_{100}=\beta_{100}\right\}$?

Comment: @Salamo: Yes. For instance, the point $\langle \alpha_3,\alpha_4,\color{red}{\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4},\alpha_2,\ldots\rangle$ works.